# Choices for persistent-ipoib.rules for a non RDMA setup? (rhel7.3)

Tags: rhel, systemd-networkd, infiniband

Im getting errors in `journalctl -xe` when i manually restart my network, not sure about on reboot, haven't check the times that closely.

My 2nd adapter is certifiably down.  It somehow seems intertwined into having gotten renamed, and applied to ipoib, not sure how.

To start with, I want to make it clear that i am Not using any kind of RDMA, i do not need any kind of super network speed, anything over 1Gb/s.

```
-- Unit user-995.slice has begun shutting down.
Feb 24 23:28:37 obfuscated.localdomain polkitd[2073]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:28030:8126178 (system
Feb 24 23:28:37 obfuscated.localdomain systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency job for unit microcode.service, ignoring: Unit is n
Feb 24 23:28:37 obfuscated.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
-- Subject: Unit network.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit network.service has begun starting up.
Feb 24 23:28:38 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: Bringing up loopback interface:  [  OK  ]
Feb 24 23:28:38 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: Bringing up interface enp2s0:  RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: [  OK  ]
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: Bringing up interface enp5s0:  ERROR    : [/etc/sysconfig/network-scr
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth[28271]: Device enp5s0 does not seem to be pre
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: [FAILED]
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain network[28036]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
-- Subject: Unit network.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit network.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service failed.
Feb 24 23:28:39 obfuscated.localdomain polkitd[2073]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:28030:8126178 (syst
lines 4317-4380/4380 (END)


$ pwd
/etc/udev/rules.d
root@obfuscated/etc/udev/rules.d$ l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root  38 Jan 26 06:29 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  51 Jan 26 17:05 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 709 Aug 23  2016 70-persistent-ipoib.rules
```

I'm a RHEL developer, is that why infiniband is even enabled like this?  Or is  this needed for other linux systems?

By the way,  I have a feeling that this started during an automatic, unbeknownst reason, that the nic renamed, on a reboot.  I have seen this happen on a RHEL6, is that some old lingering issue, or has something else gone haywire, and im just pointing out the automated responses for it? :-O

Can i just rename the persistent file to disable thie ipoib from trying to initiate at all??

Can i add another persistent-70 file for renaming my enp5oS enp4oS back to that name once and for all?

Comment: worse yet, have i been hacked over ipv6 or something?  Ive been tracking strange traffic all over the place on the local area, and might have led to an opening on this machine.